# How to let user get some files on my server

Tags: php, zip

I'm developing a page which generate some PDF files.

After generating them, I want to let users to download all the files created.

I'm on shared hosting that disable access to zip lib in PHP and I don't know how to give all the files to the user.

Any advice?

Comment: why -2? please write comment when downvote some post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to make a link of file path/address

```
  http://bla.com/folder/new.pdf


<a href="http://bla.com/folder/new.pdf">CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD pdf</a>
```

Comment: @JackTurky than either make zip file or give all of link

Comment: @JackTurky than second option give all of link

Comment: I've used all link method.. users download only the pdf that wants to have :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that ten files should be downloaded onto the clients computer. My approach would be to sent so called download headers and to then redirect the browser to the next file until all have been sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't zip, you can try to tar them with this: http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar
Or by exec command of your OS: `tar -cvwf pdf.tar pdf_files/`

After you get tar file you can link it normally with  tag.